# LWJGL3.0.0a Installation issues - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I am trying to import a library in Eclipse. This is the first time I am doing this and I am new to Eclipse, I followed YouTube videos and read other aids, but they don't work when I do it. I'm  not sure if it because I don't have a path installed or something or what...

But this is the error code when I try to run the demo script on their website.

```
Hello LWJGL 3.0.0a!
[LWJGL] GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE error
    Description : WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL
    Stacktrace  :
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1022)
        HelloWorld.init(HelloWorld.java:56)
        HelloWorld.run(HelloWorld.java:25)
        HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:113)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create the GLFW window
    at HelloWorld.init(HelloWorld.java:58)
    at HelloWorld.run(HelloWorld.java:25)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:113)
```

Comment: Seems like your "driver doesn't appear to support OpenGL" so try updating them

Comment: They should be up to date..